# How to capture audio in realtime with android microphone

Tags: android, io, microphone

Hi I have a very simple question. Does anyone know if there's a way to capture voice using the android microphone, and send it to a server in basically real time (kind of like voice-over-ip). If so does anyone have an implementation that they could link me to? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to record audio with low latency you have to use AudioRecord. AudioRecord give you the audio data which you need to send. An example for the AudioRecord usage: http://audiorecordandroid.blogspot.in/

For reference check the SipDroid-Project. https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout

tldr: 1. record using AudioRecord 2. send those audio data over UDP (or RTP/UDP)

Good luck!